# Compress file(s) in a folder individually with 'filename.extension'.zip in Windows 2016 datacenter edition using Windows default compression tool

Tags: powershell

I have a test directory D: and there are multiple folders.

D:\Data\Input;
D:\Data\Output;
D:\Data\Archive;

I want to have a script (Powershell) to run to perform the following action(s):

1. to check D:\Output\ and see if any files older than # of days (let's say 5)
2. zip the file (file1.txt > file1.txt.zip)
3. Move the zipped file to D:\Data\Archive
4. Delete the compressed file(s) in D:\Data\Output\

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items  = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Data\Output
$items | ForEach-Object {
    $lastwrite = ($_).LastAccessTime
    $timespan = New-TimeSpan -days 5 -hours 0 -Minutes 0
    
    if(((get-date) - $lastwrite) -gt $timespan){
        $name = $_.Name
        $_ | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "D:\Data\Archive\$name.zip"
        $_ | Remove-Item
    }
}
```

This is what i just came up with, should do the things you want. Next time provide some effort from your side and people and more likely willing to help :=)

Comment: Thanks so much. I am very new to development. More on the support side of it. Will try my best to start scripting.

Comment: the above code is producing the output (zipped) files with same extension. i.e: output1.csv >> output1.csv.csv (compressed), could I modify it like this:

$_ | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "D:\Data\Archive\$name" + ".zip"

Comment: $items  = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Data\Output
$items | ForEach-Object {
        $name = $_.Name
        $dest = "D:\Data\Archive\"+$name+".zip"
        $_ | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $dest
    }
Tried the above for now, without the 5 day old, I can see the .zip at the end, but still has the original file extension twice. i.e: output1.csv.csv.zip. Please assist.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Are you sure that the files are named correclty in the beginning? Even if I try with ".csv" files i have no problem and they are named correctly. Try out just "Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Data\Output" and look at the files. Are they all named correctly?

Comment: Thank you @Revicx, it was an issue with actual file itself. It had an extra '.csv' at the end. Thanks so much!